# How to fetch 2 products from every category

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to fetch 2 products from every category.

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{ 
   protected $table = 'products';
}
```

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model {
    protected $table = 'categories';
}
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::all();
    return Product::latest()->take(5)->get();
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. It would help people like me trying to answer your question if you use proper code formatting in your question. Also, which 2 products do you want to fetch? The first 2, last 2 in the category? It would help if you could edit your question accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: Define and use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) after that it becomes a lot easier

Comment: I want to fetch 2 products from each category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fetch the first two products of each category:

```
// Get all categories
$categories = Category::all();

//Create an empty array to store our product IDs
$prodIds = array();

// Extract the first 2 product IDs in each category
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $prodIds[] = $category->products->take(2)->pluck('id');
}

// Fetch products from their IDs
$products = Product::findMany($prodIds);
```

---

Edit: Also my answer above *should* work, it will fail if the category doesn't have at least two products. To fix this, you would need to remove empty values from $prodIds.

Comment: What I need to write in Models for relationship

Comment: See @Abhishek answer below for the models relationship.

Comment: I put that relationship but postman gives "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`id` in (?, ?))", this error

Answer (score 1):

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{ 
   protected $table = 'products';

  public function Category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Note : import your category model in Category model

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model {
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function Product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Note : import your category model in Product model

Controller

```
public function index() {
   
    return Category::with('Product'=>funcation($obj){
        return $obj->take(2);
    })->latest()->take(5)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$products = Product::latest()->take(2)->with('categories')->get();
```

Comment: You are getting 2 products with all their categories. The question is about getting 2 products from each category.

Comment: Yes, I did not understand the question. thank you

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it